# My object is disappearing in sculpt mode

Tags: objects, visibility

After I sculpted my object in Blender and switched to the viewport, I can no longer see it. I tried pressing tilda>view selected. All that happens is a thin orange outline of my object appears, and then disappears when I rotate it around. The grid and x and y-axis guides are also no longer there. I also tried editing the clip start setting to 0.001, also to no avail. How can I fix this?

EDIT 5/2/20: My object is now appearing in Layout and Modelling mode, but not in Sculpting mode. When I press 0 (camera view) I can see and edit my object, but as soon as a rotate the camera, the object disappears. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To solve, I increased my clip end value to $100$ in the *View* panel on the *3D View Sidebar*.